# best way to make responsive website

Tags: responsive-design

Hi i want to know which is the best and proffessional way to make a website responsive.is the % is best way to make responsive or in pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/ is the best way to make your site responsive :)

Comment: @ Deer-outdor.nl thanks for your suggestion. can you please tell me making a website in bootstrap what is the trick should i keep in mind while preparing the design in Photoshop.

Comment: Use in mind that you have 12 column grid system, so you have to make different designs for each device (PC, tablet, mobile etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to use relative width and height, so you need to use "%". But in my experiences I recommend for you some framework, for example [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to build responsive website.There is lot of pre-defined classes for responsivity.

Comment: Thanks lubos bern :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make a responsive website is to use %, because this will make your website scale..
If you use pixels, it will be an absolute.. margin so if you do top: 500px; it will go down 500px, whenever so it won't scale at all.

Comment: Why -1 my post, I answered his question, he asked about % or px, which I answered.